# AES encrypt file in C# and Java

Tags: java, c#, servlets, encryption, aes

I have encrypted file in C# with this method:

```
public byte[] Crypt(byte[] filearray, string sKey)
        {
                AesManaged DES = new AesManaged();
                DES.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sKey);
                DES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                DES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                ICryptoTransform crypt = DES.CreateEncryptor();
                byte[] cipher = crypt.TransformFinalBlock(niz, 0, filearray.Length);
                String encryptedText = Convert.ToBase64String(cipher);
                return cipher.ToArray();
            }
```

Now I try to decrypt file with Java:

```
private static byte[] transform(string base64Key, final byte[] fileBytes) throws InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchProviderException
   {
       final byte[] keyBytes = base64Key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
       final byte[] ivBytes = base64Iv.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
       final SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
       final IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
       byte[] transformedBytes = null;
       try
       {
           Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
           final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");;
           cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
           transformedBytes = cipher.doFinal(fileBytes);
       }        
       catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | 
               BadPaddingException e) 
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return transformedBytes;
   }
```

When I try to execute this function I get exception

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
>       at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher$BufferedGenericBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
>       at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)

Comment: Padding is fine. What about transferring the data in base64?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different padding, for example:

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
```

or

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
```

instead of

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
```

Comment: Could part of you answer be formatted as code, so as to make it more readable?

Comment: NoPadding is not useful padding and you have to do your padding yourself.